# Displaying a List of Strings Instead of a Displaying One String

Tags: string, common-lisp, clisp

This is just a Caesar Cipher in Common Lisp with a rotation key set to 5.

> **I have a few restrictions**
>   The input must be read and processed recursively as a list.
>   No variables, arrays, loops, progn allowed.
>   The output must be a string not a list.
>   The program must use only recursion.

```
(defun encode (expr)   ; define function funcName (argument)
  ; Out case when the list is empty
  (cond ((null expr) nil)     ; conditional (test1 action1)
  ; Checking if the expression is an atom only then to go encryption
  ((atom expr)  (encrot expr))  ; test2 see if one or less atom
  ; Adding the result of encrot to the list and
  (t(cons (encode(car expr)) (encode(cdr expr)))))) ; will run if all others fail

(defun encrot (expr)
  ; casts the object and then shifts the char by 5
  (string (int-char(encrot2 (+ 5 (char-int(char (string expr) 0)))))))

(defun encrot2 (x)
  ; Checking to see if the atom is a letter
  (cond (( > x 90) (+ 64 ( mod x 90 )))
  (( < x 91) x)))
```

My understanding is that the function cons is displaying the elements of the list as strings. For example ("A" "B" "C")

As a string it should in theory look like this `"A B C"`.

I compile using GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07) http://clisp.cons.org/.

Comment: Could you give an example (input+output)?

Comment: `cons` is displaying nothing. It's not doing any output. `cons` is only constructing a cons cell.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to convert the output list to a string is with format:

```
(format t "~{~a ~}" '(a b c)) => A B C
```

Comment: Unless you actually want the printing side-effect, it's probably better to use `(format nil ...)`

Comment: @Vatine even better!